# How to sort the results in lucene search from php file?

Tags: php, lucene

I am using lucene search in my module and my requierement is i need to sort the resultset after the search is done.  Below is the function i used for search

```
$oTextSearch->Search(array(                                                          'title'   => $aSearchString,
 'property_web_teaser' => $aSearchString,
 'content' => $aSearchString,
 'ci_publication_date' => $aSearchString                                                     
  ));
```

I have a class textsearch class, in this class search method is there. Is there any way to sort from my php model. I have searched here but i didnt find the correct one.

Comment: @Vesper what is the reason for editing my post? So that i will not repeat it for next time. Please dont think otherwise.

Comment: This is a common practice in StackOverflow to help new users improve the formatting of their posts, so that code will be highlighted, formatted using monospace font, and the entire post will look prettier and more understandable to those who would like to answer your question. You might want to read help on post formatting, to do this, press the orange question mark button in the upper right corner of "Your Answer" section right below the question and all of the answers.

Comment: This page of in the help center may explain the idea further: [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: Thankk you guys thank you very much for your explanation i will follow from next time onwards